# Compare if two vectors are the same

Tags: matlab, vector, compare

How do I check if two vectors are identical? I've tried to do it with a `for` loop and `if` statement but that option is not suited for the amount of data that I've got to work with. Is there any smart way to do it? I would like to create an `if` statement that only adds a specific vector to a matrix if there is no such vector already in my matrix.

For example if I've got a vector `[1 2 3 1 2]` in my matrix i don't want to add another vector `[1 2 3 1 2]` to the matrix.

Comment: @erfan the accepted answer says "`ismember(M,v,'rows')`". Don't you think `any(ismember(M,v,'rows'))` would be a suitable solution? If you can find an index, you can test for occurence. *Just like your answer here says so*. At least don't pretend that it's not a blatant dupe.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes, _part of my answer here_ is similar to the answer there, but as far as I know, dupe is about questions, not answers. What actually OP is asking could be answered with `isequal` and that's it. Also not related to the linked question. But if we pay attention to the details of the question, there are more to explain than what explained (and well explained) in the linked question.

Comment: @erfan it's not always constructive to be overly analytical about duplicates as long as the upvoted/accepted answers solve the question with minimal additional brain function. In simple questions like this a suitable duplicate can prevent low-quality answers popping up like mushroom...which is partly what happened here too. I believe that `ismember` of the linked duplicate solves the XY problem of OP (X="telling if a matrix contains a vector", Y="how can I test equality two vectors?"). What's *useful* for future readers (and so for SO) is to show how problems *should* be solved.

Comment: What we are discussing here is partly opinion based and partly convention and experience based. On the second one I totally rely on your opinion, since you are more experienced than me. Also excuse my words if I sounded too bold

Comment: @erfan no, don't worry, and I don't take offence very easily. I simply disagreed with your opinion, and wanted to elaborate on my own:) We can keep on disagreeing, there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

For just checking whether 2 vectors are equal you can use the `==` operator on a vector and then use `all( )` to check that every element of the returned logical array is true.  Andras Deak link in the comments has some great methods on finding a vector in a larger set.

```
v1 = [1 2 3 1 2];
v2 = [1 2 3 1 2];
returnsTrue = all(v1 == v2);
```

Comment: You should _never_ use `==` when comparing floating point numbers.  For numerical reasons you should use `all(abs(v1-v2)<tol)` where `tol` is a small numeric tolerance like `1e-10` or `eps`.

Answer (score 1):

For your question about comparing two vectors, you could use [`isequal`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html):

```
tf = isequal(vec1, vec2);
```

But as far as I understood, each vector (`vec`) is going to be a row in your final matrix (`Mat`) and you want to keep rows of `Mat` unique. If so, here are two methods to do it:

First is to check before you add a row. Use [`ismember`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) for this purpose:

```
tf = ismember(vec, Mat, 'rows'); % it gives you true if vec is a row in Mat
```

Or you can insert all vectors without checking and at the end collect the [`unique`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) rows:

```
Mat = unique(Mat, 'rows');
```

*Which one should I choose?*

This question is relevant if you have a large `Mat` and / or you want to add many `vec`s to it. In that case, if it is very probable that `vec` is already a row in `Mat`, like when the elements can only be integers in a limited range, the second method may lead to very large `Mat` before you `unique` it and therefore I wouldn't suggest it. Otherwise, the second method is more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

you could use isequal function as well

```
A1 = [1 5 6];
A2 = [1 4 3];
A3 = [1 1 1];

result = isequal(A1,A2,A3)
```

But if one of your elements will be NAN then isequal always returns 0 (false)

Comment: Way to find the corner case!